# How do I use properly PropTypes on React 15.6.0?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm starting to work with react and redux, but I'm still a little lost about how to handle props and states.

I'm getting this type error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined
>
> ```
> {name.touched && name.error && <div className="EmployeeForm-error">{name.error}</div>}
> ```

Could someone point me in the right direction or make me know what I'm doing wrong

EmployeeFormComponent.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
const EmployeeForm = ({ addEmployee, fields: {name}, handleSubmit })   => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addEmployee)} >
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          {...name}
        />
        {name.touched && name.error && <div className="EmployeeForm-error">{name.error}</div>}
      </div>
      ...
    </form>
  );}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'employee',
  fields: ['name'],
  validate,
})(EmployeeForm);
```

EmployeeFormContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import EmployeeForm from './EmployeeFormComponent';
import React from 'react';

class EmployeeFormContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <EmployeeForm {...this.props}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you console.log `this.props` in side the render() of `EmployeeFormContainer` before the return statement? What's the output?

Comment: @curlyBraces, I solved it, instead of using input I used Field from redux-form and sent the input on its component attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To solve it I modified a little my previous changing it to this, now I'm using redux-form Field, and sending the input on component attribute.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
  <div>
    <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
    {touched && error && <div className="EmployeeForm-error">{error}</div>}
  </div>
)

const EmployeeForm = ({ addEmployee, fields: { name, surname}, handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addEmployee)}>
      <div>
        <Field name="name" type="text" component={renderField} label="name"/>
      </div>
      ...
    </form>
  );}
```